# $a_n=\sum\nolimits_{i=0}^n 1/(n+i)$ I do not know how to manipulate this

Tags: calculus

$a_n=\sum\nolimits_{i=0}^n 1/(n+i)$
 I have to prove that the series converges and the limit. but i dont have a clue of how to approach it. It seems familiar to $log(1+x)$ but since $n$ is in the denominator i have difficulties to manipiulate it. Thanks in advance

Comment: do i need to use integrals ? we hadnt integrals so far, i have been doing some old exam papers.

Comment: Not all answers in the linked question use integrals, have you looked at them?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Rewrite it as
$$ \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac1{1+\frac in}$$
and observe this is a Riemann sum.

Comment: we hadnt riemann sums :/

Comment: In this case, it will be hard, because the limit is $\ln 2$, which supposes you've seen the integral.